# Как сделать автоинкремент для поля id внешней таблицы в формате "хх_тектс"?

Tags: mysql, база-данных, access

**Используется**
Access 2016
MySql

Таблицы расположены на MySql.
Access используется как клиент.

Таблицы с записями для MySql

```
-- --------------------------------------------------------
-- Хост:                         127.0.0.1
-- Версия сервера:               5.7.16 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)
-- Операционная система:         Win64
-- HeidiSQL Версия:              9.4.0.5125
-- --------------------------------------------------------

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!50503 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;

-- Дамп структуры для таблица 01tst.tst_006_01_00_org
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tst_006_01_00_org` (
  `id_org` char(50) NOT NULL,
  `org_name` text,
  `org_xar` text,
  `org_com` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_org`),
  KEY `id_org` (`id_org`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- Дамп данных таблицы 01tst.tst_006_01_00_org: ~3 rows (приблизительно)
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `tst_006_01_00_org` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `tst_006_01_00_org` (`id_org`, `org_name`, `org_xar`, `org_com`) VALUES
    ('1_org', 'org_name 1', 'org_xar 1', 'org_com 1'),
    ('2_org', 'org_name 2', 'org_xar 2', 'org_com 2'),
    ('3_org', 'org_name 3', 'org_xar 3', 'org_com 3');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `tst_006_01_00_org` ENABLE KEYS */;

-- Дамп структуры для таблица 01tst.tst_006_02_00_otd
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tst_006_02_00_otd` (
  `id_org` char(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_otd` char(50) NOT NULL,
  `otd_name` text,
  `otd_xar` text,
  `otd_comment` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_otd`),
  KEY `id_otd` (`id_otd`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- Дамп данных таблицы 01tst.tst_006_02_00_otd: ~8 rows (приблизительно)
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `tst_006_02_00_otd` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `tst_006_02_00_otd` (`id_org`, `id_otd`, `otd_name`, `otd_xar`, `otd_comment`) VALUES
    ('1_org', '1_otd', 'otd_name 1', 'otd_name 1 xar 1', 'otd_name 1 com 1'),
    ('1_org', '2_otd', 'otd_name 2', 'otd_name 2 xar 1', 'otd_name 2 com 1'),
    ('1_org', '3_otd', 'otd_name 3', 'otd_name 3 xar 1', 'otd_name 3 com 1'),
    ('2_org', '4_otd', 'otd_name 1', 'otd_name 1 xar 1', 'otd_name 1 com 1'),
    ('2_org', '5_otd', 'otd_name 2', 'otd_name 2 xar 1', 'otd_name 2 com 1'),
    ('2_org', '6_otd', 'otd_name 3', 'otd_name 3 xar 1', 'otd_name 3 com 1'),
    ('3_org', '7_otd', 'otd_name 1', 'otd_name 1 xar 1', 'otd_name 1 com 1'),
    ('3_org', '8_otd', 'otd_name 2', 'otd_name 2 xar 1', 'otd_name 2 com 1'),
    ('3_org', '9_otd', 'otd_name 3', 'otd_name 3 xar 1', 'otd_name 3 com 1');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `tst_006_02_00_otd` ENABLE KEYS */;

-- Дамп структуры для таблица 01tst.tst_006_03_00_sotr
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tst_006_03_00_sotr` (
  `id_org` text,
  `id_otd` text,
  `id_sotr` char(50) NOT NULL,
  `sotr_name` text,
  `sotr_xar` text,
  `sotr_comment` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_sotr`),
  KEY `id_sotr` (`id_sotr`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- Дамп данных таблицы 01tst.tst_006_03_00_sotr: ~2 rows (приблизительно)
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `tst_006_03_00_sotr` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `tst_006_03_00_sotr` (`id_org`, `id_otd`, `id_sotr`, `sotr_name`, `sotr_xar`, `sotr_comment`) VALUES
    ('1_org', '1_otd', '01_sotr', 'sotr_name_1', 'sotr_xar_1', 'sotr_comment 1'),
    ('1_org', '1_otd', '02_sotr', 'sotr_name_2', 'sotr_xar_2', 'sotr_comment 2'),
    ('1_org', '1_otd', '03_sotr', 'sotr_name_3', 'sotr_xar_3', 'sotr_comment 3'),
    ('1_org', '2_otd', '04_sotr', 'sotr_name_4', 'sotr_xar_1', 'sotr_comment 1'),
    ('1_org', '2_otd', '05_sotr', 'sotr_name_5', 'sotr_xar_2', 'sotr_comment 2'),
    ('1_org', '2_otd', '06_sotr', 'sotr_name_6', 'sotr_xar_3', 'sotr_comment 3'),
    ('1_org', '3_otd', '07_sotr', 'sotr_name_7', 'sotr_xar_1', 'sotr_comment 1'),
    ('1_org', '3_otd', '08_sotr', 'sotr_name_8', 'sotr_xar_2', 'sotr_comment 2'),
    ('1_org', '3_otd', '09_sotr', 'sotr_name_9', 'sotr_xar_3', 'sotr_comment 3'),
    ('2_org', '4_otd', '10_sotr', 'sotr_name_10', 'sotr_xar_1', 'sotr_comment 1'),
    ('2_org', '4_otd', '11_sotr', 'sotr_name_11', 'sotr_xar_2', 'sotr_comment 2'),
    ('2_org', '4_otd', '12_sotr', 'sotr_name_12', 'sotr_xar_3', 'sotr_comment 3'),
    ('2_org', '5_otd', '13_sotr', 'sotr_name_13', 'sotr_xar_1', 'sotr_comment 1'),
    ('2_org', '5_otd', '14_sotr', 'sotr_name_14', 'sotr_xar_2', 'sotr_comment 2'),
    ('2_org', '5_otd', '15_sotr', 'sotr_name_15', 'sotr_xar_3', 'sotr_comment 3'),
    ('2_org', '6_otd', '16_sotr', 'sotr_name_16', 'sotr_xar_1', 'sotr_comment 1'),
    ('2_org', '6_otd', '17_sotr', 'sotr_name_17', 'sotr_xar_2', 'sotr_comment 2'),
    ('2_org', '6_otd', '18_sotr', 'sotr_name_18', 'sotr_xar_3', 'sotr_comment 3'),
    ('3_org', '7_otd', '19_sotr', 'sotr_name_19', 'sotr_xar_1', 'sotr_comment 1'),
    ('3_org', '7_otd', '20_sotr', 'sotr_name_20', 'sotr_xar_2', 'sotr_comment 2'),
    ('3_org', '7_otd', '21_sotr', 'sotr_name_21', 'sotr_xar_3', 'sotr_comment 3'),
    ('3_org', '8_otd', '22_sotr', 'sotr_name_22', 'sotr_xar_1', 'sotr_comment 1'),
    ('3_org', '8_otd', '23_sotr', 'sotr_name_23', 'sotr_xar_2', 'sotr_comment 2'),
    ('3_org', '8_otd', '24_sotr', 'sotr_name_24', 'sotr_xar_3', 'sotr_comment 3'),
    ('3_org', '9_otd', '25_sotr', 'sotr_name_25', 'sotr_xar_1', 'sotr_comment 1'),
    ('3_org', '9_otd', '26_sotr', 'sotr_name_26', 'sotr_xar_2', 'sotr_comment 2'),
    ('3_org', '9_otd', '27_sotr', 'sotr_name_27', 'sotr_xar_3', 'sotr_comment 3');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `tst_006_03_00_sotr` ENABLE KEYS */;

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=IFNULL(@OLD_SQL_MODE, '') */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=IF(@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS IS NULL, 1, @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS) */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
```

**[Ссылка](http://transfiles.ru/qlv88) на файл**

Как сделать автоинкремент в формате:
- 01_тектс
- 02_тектс
- 03_тектс 
- ...
- 10_тектс

Или как сделать чтобы записи нормально сортировались?
Т.к. если делать id формате
- 1_тектс
- 2_тектс
- 3_тектс
- ...
- 10_тектс
то сортировка по умолчанию происходит по принципу см. скрин.

**Вопрос**
Как сделать автоинкремент для поля id внешней таблицы в формате "хх_тектс"?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А зачем вам id в таком формате ? автоинкремент в БД рассчитан на работу с числами и этого более чем достаточно. Если для какого то приложения вдруг потребуется запись с текствым суффиксом, то такую строку можно собрать уже в момент выдачи

Comment: @Mike `А зачем вам id в таком формате ?` - пока осваиваю.. поэтому решения могут быть нелогичны... Так... подумалось... Может нагляднее будет в подчинённой таблице видеть где чей..

Comment: Наглядно ? - Да, сразу видно откуда id. Но на этом плюсы к сожалению заканчиваются. В остальном получается, что вы сами себе создаете массу сложностей, которые придется героически преодолевать. Да и на диске эти суффиксы место занимают, индексация усложняется, скорость работы падает.

Answer (score 1):

Отвечу на ваш второй вопрос (после "или") в рамках mysql-а:

Не уверен для чего у вас остальные таблицы (mdb не анализировал, смотрел только ваши таблицы MySql), но судя по таблице tst_006_03_00_sotr у вас и так сортинг по полю id_sotr будет нормальным, т.к. есть ведущие нули.

На всякий случай я убрал эти нули из столбца id_sotr вашей таблицы tst_006_03_00_sotr, чтоб как-то сэмулитровать ваш скрин:

```
select t.* from tst_006_03_00_sotr t order by LPAD(SUBSTRING(t.id_sotr, 1, LENGTH(t.id_sotr)-5),3,'0')
```

Вот ссылка на [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/91f026/10).

Comment: Я правильно понял, что согласно вашего предложения у меня будет таблица плюс запрос с отсортированной таблицей и только с этим запросом я работаю? Т.е. например всталяю в форму Аксеса